# Can I show numbers in jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle, web-frontend

I mostly use jQuery Cycle for banner rotator, but in current work, it is required to show numbers in jQuery cycle. So is it possible to do so? If yes then how? I didn't see any such thing in documentation of jQuery Cycle and also didn't see such numbering in any demo of it.

I would rather use this plugin with numbers instead of exploring and using some other plugin.

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager.html

Comment: @Syon Yes you are right, I missed it and it is what I was looking for, if you put it in answer then I will be able to mark it as right answer.

Comment: Awesome - sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation from the Cycle Plugin to use the Pager:
[Cycle Pager - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager.html](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager.html)

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. jQuery Cycle is a well-designed plugin and it has functions you can use as callbacks that happen before and after slide transitions. Just use the `before` callback to get the number of the current slide and do something with it.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZqFA/

```
var $slideshowImages = $('.slideshow img'),
    $number = $('#number');

$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    startingSlide: 0,
    before: function (currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {

        var $img = $(nextSlideElement),
            number = $slideshowImages.index($img);

        number += 1;

        $number.text(number);
    }
});​
```

The options for the plugin are documented here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: thanks Nate but I am talking about numbering like this : http://1.s3.envato.com/files/6091024/index.html  not just numbering and yes I think Syon in comment, pointed our exactly right think I was looking for that I missed.

Comment: Gotcha. Glad you got your answer!